# Como encontrar linhas com erros em um upload de arquivo CSV?

Tags: java

Estou implementando um upload de arquivo CSV, atualmente estou conseguindo contar quantas linhas tem o **CSV**, estou conseguindo identificar quando erros existem no **CSV** como mostra no algoritmo abaixo;

```
    File arquivoLeitura = new File(getArquivo());
    LineNumberReader linhaLeitura = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(arquivoLeitura));
    linhaLeitura.skip(arquivoLeitura.length());
    int qtdLinha  = linhaLeitura.getLineNumber() + 1;


    BufferedReader leitor = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(getArquivo())));

    String linha = null;

    int indiciosComErros = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i  <= qtdLinha;  i++  ) {

            linha = leitor.readLine();
            String[] dadosCSV = linha.split(VIRGULA);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dadosCSV));
            System.out.println( dadosCSV[0]);
            System.out.println( dadosCSV[1]);

            System.out.println( dadosCSV[2]);
            System.out.println( dadosCSV[3]);
            System.out.println( dadosCSV[4]);
            System.out.println(dadosCSV[5]);
            System.out.println("--------------------------");

            if (pessoaJuridicaPublicaService.getPorId(Long.parseLong(dadosCSV[1])) == null) {
                indiciosComErros = indiciosComErros + 1;
            }



    }
        leitor.close();
```

Agora eu preciso saber quais são as linhas que estejam com erros, exemplo;

Se tiverem 50 registros e tiver um erro na linha 1 e uma outra na linha 20 que eles sejam identificados.
Se tiver 50 registros e tiver um erro na linha 10 e um outro na linha 15 e uma outro na linha 30 e um outra na linha 50 que eles sejam identificados.

Preciso de ajuda porque não tenho ideia de como realizar essa implementação!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa, eu teria uma classe para guardas os dados da linha com erro junto com o numero da linha:

```
class ErroCSV {
    private int linhaErro;
    private String[] dados;

    public ErroCSV(int linhaErro, String[] dados) {
        this.linhaErro = linhaErro;
        this.dados = dados;
    }

    public int getLinhaErro() {
        return linhaErro;
    }

    public String[] getDados() {
        return dados;
    }
}
```

E no seu codigo:

```
    List<ErroCSV> erroCSVList = new Arraylist<>();

    for (int i = 1; i  <= qtdLinha;  i++  ) {

        linha = leitor.readLine();
        String[] dadosCSV = linha.split(VIRGULA);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dadosCSV));
        System.out.println( dadosCSV[0]);
        System.out.println( dadosCSV[1]);

        System.out.println( dadosCSV[2]);
        System.out.println( dadosCSV[3]);
        System.out.println( dadosCSV[4]);
        System.out.println(dadosCSV[5]);
        System.out.println("--------------------------");

        if (pessoaJuridicaPublicaService.getPorId(Long.parseLong(dadosCSV[1])) == null) {
            erroCSVList.add(new ErroCSV(i, dadosCSV));
        }



    }
```

Com erroCSVList.size() voce tem o numero de erros e em cada item, a linha e os dados da linha com erro.:

Comment: Muito obrigado, muito obrigado mesmo :)